# Factors affecting the internal resistance of an electrolytic cell

Tags: electrical-resistance, batteries, electrochemistry

How does the internal resistance of an electrolytic cell (a source of emf) depend on

I) the concentration of the electrolyte?

II) the temperature of the cell?

Comment: A big factor is the crud that builds up on the electrodes.

Answer (score 2):

Internal resistance decreases with increase in concentration as we know that increase in concentration causes increase in ions so conductivity increases resistance decreases

As temperature increase mobility of ions increase inside electrolyte so resistance decreases